# How do I refer to APP_Data from another project

Tags: .net, asp.net, connection-string, mdf

I have the following project solution:

- There is a ASP.NET MVC Web
  Application where I have a SQL
  database (mdf file) in the App_Data directory.
- There is a class library where I
  have some migrations from
  [migratordotnet](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/). In my build file I
  have to specify where the SQL
  database is so it can run the
  migrations.

For the moment on the migration project I'm using a ***hardcoded path*** to access the SQL database in the connection string. It looks sort of like this:

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress; Integrated Security=true; AttachDbFilename=C:\MySolution\MyMVCProject\App_Data\MyDatabase.mdf"
```

This is not how I want to do. I also cannot use relative paths (such as `..\MyMVCPProject\AppData\MyDatabase.mdf` because the SQL classes used in migratordotnet won't be able to translate it right) But I want to use some kind of a substitute path to it, sort of what you'll find with `|DataDirectory|` in the `Web.Config` in the web project like this:

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

How do I do achieve this? I can't use that connection string in the migration project. Because the `|DataDirectory|` will go to .NET Framework installation path and look for the database file there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this (VB .NET code):

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress; Integrated Security=true; AttachDbFilename=" & Server.MapPath("~\App_Data\MyDatabase.mdf")
```

Server.MapPath() will turn your relative path into a fully qualified path at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered just attaching the database permanently in SQL Express?  That way you can use identical connection strings in both projects and neither will be tied to a file system path.

Comment: Nope. I'm quite new at this SQL Express thing.